# How to run Apache NiFi on Azure IoT Edge device (Ubuntu Server 18.04)?

Tags: apache-nifi, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to run apache nifi 1.15.3 on AzureIoT Edge device (Ubuntu server 18.04 VM).
I have followed all the steps from [this link](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/nifimodule). It was really helpful to understand basics, Thanks:). However, I am new to this concept, I got an error as below, while creating nifi module on azure portal.

ErrorCode:AurgumentInvalid;Property or Tag name has Invalid Characters.
[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVUq2.png)
[image]

My deployment file looks like:

[deployment file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j1Om.png)
[image]

Account name : is created azure blob storage for root certificate and flow file.
Container name: created container on storage account through azure portal and uploaded 2 file root ca certificate and flow xml file.

Is there any way to solve this issue.
How can I create nifi module through VSC from windows development machine for Linux edge device?

It would be great to receive any help:)
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small error in your deployment file. In the nifiModule, you seem to have duplicated your `desired.properties` property:

```json
{
   "properties.desired":{
      "properties.desired":{
         
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! You can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to help others find similar issues.